# Why is the auto-correct pop-up not positioned over my text?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing an app using a `UITextView` to accept user input. For some reason, the auto-correct pop-up is not positioned properly over the word that is being corrected; it's off-screen.

This is a screen shot from Spark Inspector, showing the pop-up just off screen:

[image: A keyboard with a UITextView above it, showing a misspelled word and an auto-correct pop-up just off screen]

The pop-up appears within a few pixels of the right edge of the screen (x-coordinate of 320ish), no matter where in the UITextView the word appears. The y-coordinate is usually correct (i.e., the pop-up is aligned vertically, but not horizontally).

I've verified that none of my views have any transforms applied, and the app only supports portrait mode. Help!

Comment: How do you add the text view to the view hierarchy? Input accessory? Something is throwing off the position of the text rectangle (notice the blue rectangle underneath the autocorrection.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a sample project? I would like to take a look.

Comment: I've tried calling -firstRectForRange:, which returns the CGRect I would expect.

Comment: Text view is just a subview, not an input accessory.

Comment: Please attach a demo project. If you can't reproduce, the problem lies somewhere in your code and it would be good to know either way if you can or cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a category method elsewhere in the project:

```
@implementation UIView (VFrameManipulation)

- (void)setSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.y,
                            self.frame.origin.y,
                            newSize.width,
                            newSize.height);
}

@end
```

(notice the bug?)

Apparently UIView has a private method called `-setSize`, and this category was replacing it with a buggy version.